# Storage Access Framework: Register Content Observer

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm trying to implement a `ContentObserver` on a Storage Access Framework provided `Uri`, but the observer is never notified of any change.

The example `Uri` I'm attempting to observe is:
`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMusic/document/primary%3AMusic`

The app has previously been granted the `READ_URI_PERMISSION`, via `takePersistableUriPermission`.

I've tried using the `Uri` returned from `DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree` (which resolves to `/tree/primary:Music/document/primary:Music/children`).

I've also tried `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri)` (which resolves to `/tree/primary:Music/document/primary:Music`).

I've tested adding and removing files directly to this `Music` directory via adb and using the Files app on the device, but the `ContentObserver` `onChange()` callbacks are never called.

I have noticed that when registering the same `ContentObserver` against `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, I do receive change notifications - so there doesn't appear to be a problem with the `ContentObserver` implementation. Unfortunately, some of the directories I'd like to observe are not tracked in the `MediaStore`.

Comment: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMusic/document/primary%3AMusic`. Please tell how you obtained that uri.

Comment: `(which resolves to ...` No not to those. Uries start with content://.

Comment: Why dont you use `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AMusic` ?

Comment: The `com.android.externalstorage/` uri is obtained via.a user selected directory from the default Android document provider. 

When I say 'resolves' to, I mean this is the output of Uri.toString() for those uri's. The url scheme and authority have been omitted.

I'm not using the uri you suggested because a) I believe the uri must include a document tree in order for the SAF to determine your app has permission to access the files in that tree and b) I'm not sure how I would obtain a reference to that uri, when I have a document tree uri in hand.

Comment: `provider. When I say 'resolves' to, I mean this is the output of Uri.toString() ` Impossible outcome. Maybe you used Uri.getPath(). Further you talk abacadabra too.

Comment: Oh, yes I think I may have printed the path actually