# Register content observer on external storage

Tags: android

My app has read and write permissions on an arbitrary folder of the user's selection, per Storage Access Framework's ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. That yields a tree uri. However, I have found that the ContentObserver class is not monitoring file changes on and below that uri. `onChange()` below is never called when the user creates/edits/renames/deletes the text files within.

```
    val contentObserver = object : ContentObserver(null) {
        override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
            Log.v("myapp", "change detected")
        }
        override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean, uri: Uri?) {
            Log.v("myapp", "change detected")
        }
    }

    requireActivity().contentResolver.registerContentObserver(tree_uri, true, contentObserver)
```

Perhaps a similar question to this: [Storage Access Framework: Register Content Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796380/storage-access-framework-register-content-observer)

Running on API level 29 in this case.